# why does the set itself is neither closed nor open in trivial topology

Tags: general-topology, analysis

> A set can be neither open nor closed or both open and closed. In a  discrete topology,  every set $A\subset\mathcal{S}$ is both open and closed, whereas, in a trivial topology, any set $A\neq\emptyset$ or $\mathcal{S}$ is neither open nor closed.

The link is here [on page 2](https://bose.res.in/%7Eamitabha/diffgeom/chap1.pdf)

I could understand in the discrete topology, every subset of $\mathcal{S}$ are in the topology so they are open by definition. since their complement is also in the topology,which means the complements are open so they are also closed.

**Questions**

1. Does $\emptyset$ and $\mathcal{S}$ both open and closed in trivial topology? I find both are open under trivial topology on the wiki, I think they are closed as well like the above reasoning.
2. In trivial topology, I don't know why the set itself $\mathcal{S}$ is neither open nor closed in the notes.

Please help me out with these two questions, thank you so much.

Comment: The whole set and the empty set are open and closed in every topology. In the indiscrete (or trivial as the article calls it) topology, the only open and closed sets are the whole set and the empty set. That's why no other sets are open or closed under that topology. The trivial topology is the minimum topology you can have.

Comment: You say "I don't know why the set itself is neither open nor closed in the notes", but the notes you quote say "in a trivial topology, any set $A \neq \emptyset$ or $S$ is neither open nor closed." I'm guessing you're just misreading this. The notes don't say anything about $\emptyset$ and $S$ (they say that everything else is not open and not closed), because they're always both open and closed anyway.

Comment: @Magdiragdag yeah, I misread it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The empty set and the whole set are always open, by definition of a topology. Being the complement of each other they are always closed.
2. In the notes is said that any subset $A$, $A \neq S$, $A \neq \emptyset$ is neither oper nor closed for the trivial topology.

Answer (score 1):

The set itself, the whole set, is clopen (open and closed) in the trivial topology. In fact in any topology.

In the discrete topology,  everything is clopen.

There's a few arguments for why this is so.  Remember an arbitrary union of open sets is open.

Work from the definitions.   You start with open sets.   Then closed sets are the ones whose *complements* are open.